# Нет инерционной прокрутки на iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3, iphone

Выявил на сайте такую проблему, причем она присутствует только на iPhone.
Если попытаться скроллить пальцем страницу вниз, проведя пальцем и отпустив его от экрана на andriod страница как бы по инерции скроллится вниз еще некоторое время. На iPhone же все сразу останавливается. Более того чтобы прокрутить нужно прямо с усилием пальцем вести. 
Кто чего подскажет, может сталкивались с подобным?
Сайт посмотреть можно тут: http://myiconskin.sopteh.beget.tech/

UPD: Событие scroll такое есть:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $menu = $('#logo');
var $menufix = $('#logo_fix');
$('body').scroll(function(){
        if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 1 && $menu.hasClass('normal') && $menufix.hasClass('hide') ){
                $menu.removeClass('normal').addClass('hide');
                $menufix.removeClass('hide').addClass('normal');
        }
        else if($(this).scrollTop() <= 1 && $menu.hasClass('hide') && $menufix.hasClass('normal')) {
                $menu.removeClass('hide').addClass('normal');
                $menufix.removeClass('normal').addClass('hide');
        }
});
```

});

Comment: Вероятно, есть функция-обработчик события scroll. Если такая имеется, покажите код.

Comment: Из последнего что добавлял добавил в сообщение. До этого вроде бы со scroll ничего не делал, но сайт уже тогда плохо пролистывался.

Comment: Попробуй временно отключить Slideout.js и проверь. Возможно что-то с ним не так.

Comment: Стало чуть лучше. Не тормозит ,по крайней мере) Раньше даже пальцем сдвигалось с трудом. Но скролл пока не заработал (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, кому-то пригодится. Проблема решается css стилем для контейнера. В конкретно моем примере решилось стилем для body

```
body {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```